# Import failing for java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, date, java-time

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

    public class DateDiff {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            /** The date at the end of the last century */
            LocalDate endofCentury = LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 31);
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

            Period diff = Period.between(endofCentury, now);

            System.out.printf("The 21st century (up to %s) is %s old%n", now, diff);
            System.out.printf("The 21st century is %d years, %d months and %d days old",
                    diff.getYears(), diff.getMonths(), diff.getDays());
        }
    }
```

Local Date is not being found am I missing an import directive

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 9):

Check if you're using JDK 8.
I guess you're not and that's your issue.